# RxJS - Tell observable to wait for other observable to emit non null value

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs6, angular11

I've got this setter which assigns a class member observable `systemAreasOptions$`. I do it there because it needs to wait for `mappedItem$` to have had an emission which is not null. I originially had `systemAreasOptions$` assigned at the class level, but it did not wait for `mappedItem$`. For some   reason I couldn't even get the HTML to rerender when using the `asyncPipe`. How do I tell an observable (`systemAreasOptions$` to wait for another observable (`mappedItem$`), instead of just assigning it where the other one emits?

```
public set mappedItem(mappedItem: IPermissionsMappedItem) {
    mappedItem.hydrate$Permissions().then(_ => {
        this.mappedItem$.next(mappedItem);
        this.systemAreasOptions$ = from(
            this.lookupService.SYSTEM_AREAS.toNestedLookup()
                .$promise as unknown as Observable<IPermissmissionsLookup[]>
        ).pipe(
            map(systemAreas => orderBy(systemAreas,systemArea => systemArea?.label?.toLowerCase())),
            map(systemAreas => systemAreas.map(area => ({
                ...area,
                permissions: this.getPermissionsForArea(area.id)
            }))),
            shareReplay(1),
            tap(console.log)
        );

        this._subscriptions.add(
            this.systemAreasOptions$.subscribe(
                this.systemAreasOptionsBehaviourSubject$)
        );
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can combine the observables:

- Create an observable that only emits mappedItems that aren't null
- Emit both values only when it emits

I beleave you are looking for withLatestFrom:

```js
higherOrder$ = mappedItemThatIsNotNull$.pipe(
  withLatestFrom(systemAreasOptions$)
)
```

In your template:

```html
higherOrder$ | async
```

This will yield [mappedItem, systemAreaOptions]